# Reading a webpage in Eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is the code that is supposed to read a text from a specified website but the variable "result" simply gives me no output. I can't get the function main(null) running. it simply crashes the app whenever or wherever it is called. (am calling in onCreate() of MainActivity)

```
    public class ConvertUrlToString {

         public void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                webPage = "http://www.albab.pk/albab_edu/mashal/dsms.aspx";
                URL url = new URL(webPage);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                int numCharsRead;
                char[] charArray = new char[1024];
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
                    sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
                }
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
        sms.sendTextMessage("+923018744545", null, "Hi There!", piSent, piDelivered);
    }

public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: the problem is that i can't get the ConvertURLToString.main(null) running. it simply crashes the app. can anyone help me with what is the error in the code for reading the web content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and I've tested it. It works. Please check whether you have given [internet permission](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client). Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Also since you say "eclipse android", i assume your are trying it via emulator. In this case check whether you machine is behind any proxy? If so you need to add appropriate system properties as well.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "your host name/ip");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "your host port");
```

When i say it works, I am just taking about the main() method. When you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(result), 0);` you should ensure that the result value is set before the click, i.e, verify whether the main method is invoked before the click event.